# get a self join recursive for base id dynamically

Tags: oracle

I have a table that have a parent/child structure
which the parent column point on the child column
the child could be a parent or an ancestor...so I want the base Id for that parent
this could be 3,4,5...etc. levels or even 1 level...
this is the output that should be

[image]

```
    select 
    ID, 
    REF_ID, 
    ROUND_ID, 
    PARENT.ID BASE_ID --- HERE SHOULD BE THE ROOT ID OF THE PARENT
    FROM 
    TAB CHILD LEFT JOIN 
    TAB PARENT 
ON PARENT.ID = CHILD.REF_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query and find the leaves of the hierarchy:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS id, 
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT ref_id AS ref_id, 
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT round_id AS round_id, 
       id AS base_id
FROM   TAB
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ref_id = id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab (id, ref_id, round_id) AS
SELECT  1, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 1,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 2,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 3,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 4,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, NULL, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 8,    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 9,    3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 19, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | REF_ID | ROUND_ID | BASE_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | *null* | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | *null* | 1 | 2 |
> | 3 | *null* | 1 | 3 |
> | 4 | *null* | 1 | 4 |
> | 5 | *null* | 2 | 5 |
> | 6 | *null* | 2 | 6 |
> | 7 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
> | 8 | *null* | 2 | 8 |
> | 9 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
> | 10 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
> | 11 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
> | 12 | *null* | 2 | 12 |
> | 13 | *null* | 2 | 13 |
> | 14 | *null* | 2 | 14 |
> | 15 | *null* | 3 | 15 |
> | 16 | 8 | 3 | 8 |
> | 17 | *null* | 3 | 17 |
> | 18 | 9 | 3 | 2 |
> | 19 | *null* | 3 | 19 |
> | 20 | *null* | 3 | 20 |
> | 21 | *null* | 3 | 21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3b1e858aa69b92d3e1d15085df806a48)*